# .gltf model exported from Cinema 4D not loading in Angular threejs

Tags: angular, three.js, gltf, cinema-4d

I want to add a model exported from Cinema 4D to a 3D scene in Angular, I have written the code below but the model doesn't show and the scene is black. I need help!!!

Testing the same code from this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-j1yzza?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,  the created object works fine but loading object doesn't work.

What do I do, how can fix this?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from  'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-playground',
  templateUrl: './playground.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./playground.page.scss'],
})
export class PlaygroundPage implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() { 
    // set up scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // controls

    // load headphone model
    var loader = new GLTFLoader();

    loader.load('../../assets/main/headphone.gltf', function (model) {

      model.scene.traverse(c => {
        c.castShadow = true;
      });

      // add model
      scene.add(model.scene);

      // add light
      var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.8);
      scene.add(ambientLight);

      var pointLight1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFF0040, 4 ,50);
      scene.add(pointLight1);

      var pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight(0x0040FF, 3 ,50);
      scene.add(pointLight2);
      
      var pointLight3 = new THREE.PointLight(0x80FF80, 4 ,50);
      scene.add(pointLight3);

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    },
      undefined, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

}
```

Comment: if you share the object `headphone.gltf` it'd be easier

Comment: Please download the model from https://drive.google.com/file/d/14aEuq9hUeerUT0tSMW4yWFHa8p4HmVb-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The model appears correctly in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/, so it's exporting correctly and loading fine in three.js. It looks like you're putting both the model and the camera at `0,0,0`, maybe that's why you can't see it? Try using OrbitControls as shown here: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls

Comment: @DonMcCurdy works fine now. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The model appears correctly in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/, so it's exporting correctly and loading fine in three.js. It looks like you're putting both the model and the camera at 0,0,0, maybe that's why you can't see it? Try using OrbitControls as shown here: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls